# I am looking for the reason why I get TypeError: x is undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I get an error when running my code, but it does remove the elements as expected.

I have tried to use a querySelectorAll but that gave me "slet.style is undefined"

```
    if (document.URL.indexOf("/catalog/categories/departments/") > -1) {
    var allProducts = document.getElementsByClassName("threeColumn product");
    for (var i = 0; i < allProducts.length; i++) {

    var slet = document.getElementsByTagName("mark")[i];
    slet.style.display = "none";
    console.log("This is here now");
        }
   }
```

I want the code to not display the element named mark on all pages that include /catalog/categories/departments/ in the URL. 
It does display:none but i get an error message:

```
"TypeError: slet is undefined" But I think I already defined it in the "slet" var?
```

Answer (score 1):

If `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an empty `HTMLCollection`, then `document.getElementsByTagName()[i]` returns `undefined`, so `slet` IS `undefined`. It doesn't mean your variable `slet` does not exist - which would raise a `ReferenceError` - but that it's *value* is the special `undefined` object.

Comment: Thx @lennholm for having fixed the missing part 8-)